# Open source implementations for GPS+IMU sensor fusion?

Tags: kalman-filter, imu, sensor-fusion, gps

Are there any Open source implementations of GPS+IMU sensor fusion (loosely coupled; i.e. using GPS module output and 9 degree of freedom IMU sensors)? -- kalman filtering based or otherwise.

I did find some open source implementations of IMU sensor fusion that merge accel/gyro/magneto to provide the raw-pitch-yaw, but haven't found anything that includes GPS data to provide filtered location and speed info.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The px4 software for the pixhawk autopilot has an extended kalman filter that uses an accelerometer, a gyroscope, gps, and mag.

A paper describing the a smaller ekf which only estimates attitude [can be found on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326184615/https://pixhawk.org/firmware/apps/attitude_estimator_ekf) and code for the full ekf can be found on [github](https://github.com/priseborough/InertialNav) with further information [on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730022711/https://pixhawk.org/firmware/apps/ekf_att_pos_estimator).

Comment: Awbmilne updated these links in their [answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/20547/37), so I have updated this answer with those links.

Answer (score 4):

ROS has a package called robot_localization that can be used to fuse IMU and GPS data. This package implements Extended and Unscented Kalman filter algorithms.
The package can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization).

Comment: Thanks JuliusG. 
I didn't mention earlier, but my use case involves logging the GPS and IMU data (using embedded device), which after the usage scenario is transferred to a server and thats where I plan on performing the sensor fusion as a post-processing activity. I've just started looking at ROS and looks like it can be helpful for my use-case.

Please let me know if you think otherwise.
(my application is not exactly robotics, but I am seeking help here because sensor fusion is a fairly common thing in robotics)

Comment: I believe you will find ROS very useful. It has a lot of tools not only for sensor fusion but for data visualization etc.

Answer (score 2):

A followup on holmeski's reply.

It seems those pages have been taken down.
I found the old webpages on the 'Way Back Machine'.

1. [Pixhawk Attitude Estimator (EKF)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326184615/https://pixhawk.org/firmware/apps/attitude_estimator_ekf)
2. [Pixhawk ekf_att_pos_estimator (Application)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730022711/https://pixhawk.org/firmware/apps/ekf_att_pos_estimator)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Awbmilne. On stack exchange, it is better to suggest an edit to an answer rather than adding another answer which clarifies it. Newer answers tend to languish unseen at the bottom of the page, so editing an answer with outdated information to update it with new information, especially if it's updating links, makes the information much more readily accessible. I've edited your links into holmeski's answer.